# When I run Android JUnit Test, nothing happens

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

Just for some more information, I am using an Android JUnit test that I downloaded online from an Android course (on coursera), and when I run the test, nothing happens, as in nothing pops up and I get no notifications.

Does anyone know what I could possibly be missing?
I'm getting no console, or LogCat outputs at all.

Comment: Walk us through what you're doing. What steps are you taking to attempt to run the jUnit tests?

Comment: @Smittey Sorry for the late response, but I finally figured it out. I was not using the correct API version and didn't have the correct AVD for the emulator.